# Editing a column inside a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to edit my column inside the dataframe i tried using `tstrsplit` but I didnt get the desired result. i am trying to remove `';'` from OID & i want single value in every row in OID column.

this is my code below i did

```
library(data.table);
setDT(df)[, paste0("OID", 1:3) := tstrsplit(OID, ";", fixed = TRUE)]
```

doing this code it created 3 different columns OID1 OID2 OID3 but i need to only edit column OID & have single values in it has displayed below in my desired output.

here below is my data-->

```
   QID           OID
      189       204;202;201;203;  
      189       202;203;201;204;  
      189        na
      189       204;202;201;203;
      189        na
      189       204;202;201;203;
      189        na
```

my desired output what i need is below-->

```
QID       OID
189       202
189       201
189       204
189       203
```

Comment: But can you elaborate on how to get that output from the above mentioned input? I am unable to establish relation between input and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need a single element from each row, we can split the 'OID' by `;`, loop through the `list` output with `sapply`, get a single element with (`sample` - as the rules are not clear), and update the 'OID' with that output.

```
transform(df, OID = sapply(strsplit(OID, ";"), sample, 1))
#  QID OID
#1 189 202
#2 189 204
#3 189 203
#4 189 202
```

If we need `unique` values per row

```
transform(df, OID = sample(unique(unlist(strsplit(OID, ";")))))
#  QID OID
#1 189 202
#2 189 201
#3 189 203
#4 189 204
```

NOTE: If the "OID" column class is `factor`, convert to `character` class before splitting i.e. `strsplit(as.character(OID), ";")`

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(QID = c(189L, 189L, 189L, 189L),
OID = c("204;202;201;203;", 
"202;203;201;204;", "204;202;201;203;", "204;202;201;203;")), 
.Names = c("QID", "OID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: @peeyush It is not giving me any error.  Without showing the error, it is not easy to comment what you are doing wrong.  Do you have a `factor` column?

Comment: @peeyush I showed the data in my post.  It is not giving any errors.  If you can update your post with the `dput` output of your data, it will be great

Comment: I also tried akrun's code, it should be all right. May be your original dataframe has some format problem?

Comment: @peeyush please edit your post with the new requirements as it is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think another option is using the library `stringr::str_split_fixed`, it vectorised over string, so it should be more efficient than sapply.

`str_split_fixed(string, pattern, n)`

Please see here: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/stringr/docs/str_split_fixed

```
df <- data.frame(QID=c(189,189,189,189),
                 OID=c("204;202;201;203","202;203;201;204",
                       "204;202;201;203","204;202;201;203"))
df

#       QID             OID
# 1 189 204;202;201;203
# 2 189 202;203;201;204
# 3 189 204;202;201;203
# 4 189 204;202;201;203


library(stringr)

df$OID = str_split_fixed(df$OID, ";",4)[,1] #get the first seperated column
df

#  QID OID
#1 189 204
#2 189 202
#3 189 204
#4 189 204
```